# Interpretation of the second continous group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, galois-cohomology

In regular group cohomology theory, it is well known that $\mathrm{H^2(G,A)} \cong \mathrm{Ext(G,A)}$, where $\mathrm{Ext(G,A)}$ denotes the class of all groups $\mathrm{U}$ which make the following sequence exact: $$\mathrm{0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow U \rightarrow G \rightarrow 1}$$
and the action of $\mathrm{G}$ on $\mathrm{A}$, is the same as the conjugation by the corresponding element from $\mathrm{U}$.

What about the case when $\mathrm{G}$ is a pro-finite group and one considers $\mathrm{H_{cont}^2(G,A)}$ instead of the regular cohomology? Is there a similiar interpretation to the above isomorphism, say, for example, the class of groups $\mathrm{U}$ with the same property but with continous arrows? In other words, may one writes something like that $\mathrm{H_{cont}^2(G,A)} \cong \mathrm{Ext_{cont}(G,A)}$ (If the right object really exist)?

I am familiar with the relation to Brauer groups, but I like to work with group extensions.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try just to follow the same proof as in the case when $G$ is discrete? One can define the notion of a continuous extension of a topological group (with a topological normal subgroup) as one which admits a continuous (nonequivariant) section.

Comment: It is possible, I haven't tried that since I am not familiar with all the steps of the proof. I know how to show an equivalnce between Ext and H2 as pointed sets.